# Conditional or must with はず in と、ならないはずの

Tags: grammar

One of [NHK's stories](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012410471000/k10012410471000.html) today is about parents delaying routine vaccines, and it has the following line:

ワクチンを受けるのが遅く**なると、ならないはずの**病気になったり、病気がひどくなったりします

I'm interpreting it something like: if you get the vaccine late, then you will definitely get the illness and the illness might get worse. Or perhaps, you must not get the vaccine late or you will surely get the illness or it might get worse.

I feel like I understand ~たりする, and と、ならない but the bold portion above is really throwing me.

Comment: ならないはずの病気になる = You'll get an illness you wouldn't have contracted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aeon Akechi has largely answered your question with his comment, but I will expand a little.

In short, the sentence breaks down like this:

> ワクチンを受けるのが遅くなると
>
> If you get the vaccine late
>
> [ ならないはずの病気 ]になったり、病気がひどくなったりします
>
> You will get an illness you (otherwise) wouldn't have, or your illness will be worse.

I think you were pretty close to parsing this correctly, but the important thing is that `ならないはずの` is just qualifying `病気`. This `なる` comes from [病気になる](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%97%85%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B), so this `ならないはず` is an expression of the expectation that under normal circumstances this is something you wouldn't catch.

I chose `illness will be worse` over `get worse` because this is talking about contracting the illness, and presumably not people who already have it.